# Issue with odeint and class

Tags: python, odeint

I am trying to use a simple ordinary diff equation in a class and solve it with odeint. Without using classes everything works ok, but with a class I get the error:

```
---> 18         return self.u()/self.Vd - (self.Cl/self.Vd)*C
---> 12         if self.t % self.tau <= self.infusion:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

The class code:

```
class modelCmt1():
    def __init__(self, Vd, Cl, infusion, dose, tau, t):
        
        self.Vd = Vd
        self.Cl = Cl 
        self.infusion = infusion
        self.dose=dose
        self.tau=tau
        self.t = t
    
    def u(self):
        
        if self.t % self.tau <= self.infusion:
            return self.dose/self.infusion
        else:
            return 0
        
    def diffEq(self, C, t, Vd, Cl):
        return self.u()/self.Vd - (self.Cl/self.Vd)*C
```

Use:

```
Cinitial = 0
Vd=22.4
Cl=6
dose=1000
tau=8
infusion=3
t = np.linspace(0,24,100)

model = modelCmt1(infusion,dose,tau,t)
solve = odeint(model.diffEq, Cinitial, t, args=(Vd,Cl))
```

Expected plot:
[image]

If I use self.t.any() or self.t.all() I get the wrong plot:
[image]

Comment: Have you searched for the error message on the internet? What did you find? Why did it not help you solve the problem? Have you tried to do what the error message says?

Comment: It's unclear to me what exactly you mean by "without classes". This problem doesn't have to do with classes. Maybe if you don't have this class you also don't have the code that gives the error.

Comment: "without classes" I mean just two functions, u(t) and diffEq(C,t,Vd,Cl). If I put self.t.any() or self.t.all() and plot the differential eq. I get the wrong result

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by removing self.t, and passing directly t like this:

```
class modelCmt1():
    def __init__(self, Vd, Cl, infusion, dose, tau, t):
        
        self.Vd = Vd
        self.Cl = Cl
        self.infusion = infusion
        self.dose=dose
        self.tau=tau
       
    
    def u(self, t):
        
        if t % self.tau <= self.infusion:
            return self.dose/self.infusion
        else:
            return 0
        
    def diffEq(self, C, t, Vd, Cl):
        return self.u(t)/self.Vd - (self.Cl/self.Vd)*C
```

Use:

```
Cinitial = 0
Vd=22.4
Cl=6
dose=1000
tau=8
infusion=3
t = np.linspace(0,24,100)

model = modelCmt1(Vd,Cl,infusion,dose,tau,t)
solve = odeint(model.diffEq, Cinitial, t, args=(Vd,Cl))
plt.plot(t,solve)
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]